# WPF change button style to change cursor when disabled?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-4.0

I have tried the following method to update the cursor of a button when `IsEnabled` is `False`:

```xml
<Button Content="Test" IsEnabled="False">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="No"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

However the button cursor will not change... If I were to try and change other properties such as the Background however this would work fine... Can someone please explain why this is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mouse over events cannot fire when the element is disabled. Cursors will change based on mouse movements. To solve this, place another element say rectangle over the button and change its cursor when the button is disabled. Hide the rectangle by making its opacity "0". **(No Visibility="Collapsed").**

```
   <Grid>
        <Button Content="Blah"
                x:Name="btn"
                IsEnabled="False" />
        <Rectangle Opacity="0"
                   Fill="Transparent">
            <Rectangle.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsEnabled}"
                                     Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Cursor"
                                    Value="No" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Rectangle.Style>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: haha I didnt even think about the fact that mouse events would stop when disabled, thanks for the reminder I should probably test stuff before I type it at someone lol. +1

Comment: The Rectangle is not inside Button's Content. Rectangle and Button, both are in same container (Grid).

Comment: Ah yeah I just missed the buttons tag was self closing sorry.